# Two different Imported modules with same code structure sharing the same function reference

Tags: node.js

I have two modules with the same code in a different/same directory. It returns an object with the closure. The returned object has two property init and log. init method takes a function as an argument and assigns it to the closure.

```
// module1.js
module.exports = function () {
    var moduleInstance = this;

    moduleInstance.logger = function () {
        console.log('module 1 default logger')
    };
    return {
        init: function (logger) {
            moduleInstance.logger = logger
        },
        log: function () {
            console.log('in module 1 log function');
            moduleInstance.logger();
        }
    }
}();

// ./module2.js
module.exports = function () {
    var moduleInstance = this;

    moduleInstance.logger = function () {
        console.log('module 2 default logger')
    };
    return {
        init: function (logger) {
            moduleInstance.logger = logger
        },
        log: function () {
            console.log('in module 2 log function');
            moduleInstance.logger();
        }
    }
}();
```

in my code if i import 2 modules:

```
const module1 = require('./module1');
const module2 = require('./module2');
module1.init(function () {
    console.log('logger 1')
});
module2.init(function () {
    console.log('logger 2')
});
module1.log(); 
module2.log();

// expected output
// in module 1 log function
// logger 1
// in module 2 log function
// logger 2

// actual output
// in module 1 log function
// logger 2 
// in module 2 log function
// logger 2
```

as per the documents, the node should cache the module based on the filename. But here it is not working as expected.

Need to understand how this is working?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem: `var moduleInstance = this;`. `this` refers to `module.exports` object, so in your code you actually set and reset again `module.exports.logger = ...`. Replace this line with `var moduleInstance = {};` and you will get the expected results:

```
in module 1 log function
logger 1
in module 2 log function
logger 2
```